# Django - possible to send POST variables from view?

Tags: django, redirect, post, request, django-views

This is part of one of my views:

```
@login_required
def cropView(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if 'x1' and 'y1' and 'x2' and 'y2' in request.POST:
            xOne=request.POST['x1']
            yOne=request.POST['y1']
            xTwo=request.POST['x2']
            yTwo=request.POST['y2']
```

The URL which leads to this view is

```
/cropView/
```

Normally, the cropView would receive a POST request from this form:

```
<form method="post" action="/cropView/">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" size="4" id="x1" name="x1" value=0 />
    <input type="hidden" size="4" id="y1" name="y1" value=0 />
    <input type="hidden" size="4" id="x2" name="x2" value=120 />
    <input type="hidden" size="4" id="y2" name="y2" value=120 />
    <input type="submit" value='Submit' />
 </form>
```

Is it possible for me to redirect to this /cropView/ from another view while sending POST variables? For example, I need another view like this (sudo code):

```
def redirectToCropView(request):
    variables = {
        x1 = 0,
        y1 = 0,
        x2 = 120,
        y2 = 120,
    }

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cropView/') with variables as request.POST
```

Basically, I want to create the variables in another view and redirect to /cropView/' with the variables accessible in request.POST. Is this possible?

Comment: Just curious, why would you need two views here?

Comment: @ruddra Each user has an image, and can create a thumbnail of that image. The 1st view is if the user gives the coordinates of the thumbnail, and the 2nd view is if the user just uploads an image and doesn't give any coordinates for the image. In this case, I give the default coordinates (0, 0, 120, 120) and create a thumbnail. Creating the thumbnail requires the exact same code in both views. The only different between the two views is that the first view receives the coordinates from request.POST information, and the second view just uses the default coordinates. The 2 views r 90% the same.

Comment: I see. but what if you define in one view that if user doesn't give any coordinate then you will use (0,0,120,120) else user's given coordinate?

Comment: @ruddra user can chose to 'crop existing image' or 'upload image'.. when user uploads image, the view creates a default thumbnail using default variables, "and then crops". When user crops existing image, view uses request.post variables, "and then crops". The "and then crops" code is the exact same. So one view first uploads the image and then crops with default variables and the other view simply crops with request.POST. The only time no variables are in POST (and when I need to use the default variables) is when user uploads an image. Image uploading is not handles by cropView.